# Questions about ZF-Oauth "official" database schema

Tags: php, mysql, oauth-2.0, zend-framework2, laminas-api-tools

I have a couple of questions about zf-oauth (Apigility), and php-oauth server database schema.

The database schema is:

```
CREATE TABLE oauth_clients (
    client_id VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
    client_secret VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
    redirect_uri VARCHAR(2000) NOT NULL,
    grant_types VARCHAR(80),
    scope VARCHAR(2000),
    user_id VARCHAR(255),
    CONSTRAINT clients_client_id_pk PRIMARY KEY (client_id)
);
CREATE TABLE oauth_access_tokens (
    access_token VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    client_id VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
    user_id VARCHAR(255),
    expires TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    scope VARCHAR(2000),
    CONSTRAINT access_token_pk PRIMARY KEY (access_token)
);
CREATE TABLE oauth_authorization_codes (
    authorization_code VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    client_id VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
    user_id VARCHAR(255),
    redirect_uri VARCHAR(2000),
    expires TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    scope VARCHAR(2000),
    id_token VARCHAR(2000),
    CONSTRAINT auth_code_pk PRIMARY KEY (authorization_code)
);
CREATE TABLE oauth_refresh_tokens (
    refresh_token VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    client_id VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
    user_id VARCHAR(255),
    expires TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    scope VARCHAR(2000),
    CONSTRAINT refresh_token_pk PRIMARY KEY (refresh_token)
);
CREATE TABLE oauth_users (
    username VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR(2000),
    first_name VARCHAR(255),
    last_name VARCHAR(255),
    CONSTRAINT username_pk PRIMARY KEY (username)
);
CREATE TABLE oauth_scopes (
    type VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT "supported",
    scope VARCHAR(2000),
    client_id VARCHAR (80),
    is_default SMALLINT DEFAULT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE oauth_jwt (
    client_id VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
    subject VARCHAR(80),
    public_key VARCHAR(2000),
    CONSTRAINT jwt_client_id_pk PRIMARY KEY (client_id)
);
```

You can find it at:

https://github.com/zfcampus/zf-oauth2

https://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/

https://apigility.org/documentation/modules/zf-oauth2

So, this schema seems really "standard" because is adopted by Zend Technologies (zend framework and apigility), but I have some questions:

1. Why aren't any "ordinary" primary keys? (int auto increment field). 
   I would to use `oauth_users` table for registration account and the form's fields are "email" and "password". I could store email into `oauth_users.username` field, but It does not seem a good idea to use this field as a foreign key. Finally, my url looks better in `profile-url/[:id]` than `profile-url/[:username/]` (email in my case). So, I have to create a custom primary key or I could go against problems?
2. Why aren't any foreign keys? this questions is related to the first. I have to add foreign keys or I could go against problems? using `oauth_users.username` as foreign key for my other tables, It does not seem a good idea.

Comment: 1) Part of the reason is to support major databases with one query (here is merge request to package used by apigility that addresses this issue https://github.com/bshaffer/oauth2-server-php/pull/149). With auto increment you would loose PostgreSQL for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in the composer json require list `ZF-Oauth2` is built on top of [`bshaffer/oauth2-server-php`](https://github.com/zfcampus/zf-oauth2/blob/master/composer.json#L22) for which you can find the original documentation [here](http://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/). It has some nice explanations on the working of OAuth2. It is also the same repository that @Adam is referring to.

You can definitely customize these OAuth modules to a certain extend (like use your own table names). To do this you can introduce a custom `OAuthAdapter` with your own logic. There are also other modules available that do exactly that, like for example [this `zf-oauth2-doctrine` module](https://github.com/API-Skeletons/zf-oauth2-doctrine) that is made for using OAuth2 with Doctrine 2.

That one comes with the following database diagram 
(source: https://github.com/API-Skeletons/zf-oauth2-doctrine):

[image]